# Update ng-repeat values in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am listing some elements and each element has a click event and as a parameter the same element.

```
<a class="item item-avatar item-lista" ng-click="verView({{$index}},{{view}})">
```

Function verView :

```
$scope.verView = function(index,view){
   sessionService.set("view_leido",view);
   $location.path("/event/view/"+index);
}
```

Function darLike:

```
$scope.darLike = function(view_id, index){
console.log(UrlService.url+'likeView/'+sessionService.get("user_id")+'/'+sessionService.get("hash")+"/"+view_id+"/");
$http({method: 'GET', url: UrlService.url+'likeView/'+sessionService.get("user_id")+'/'+sessionService.get("hash")+"/"+view_id+"/"})
.success(function(data){
  if(data.status == 1){
    angular.copy(data.view.TableView, $scope.views[index]);
  }
})
.error(function(){

})
.finally(function(){

});
}
```

These elements can be given LIKE this creates a record in my database and return the number of Likes having my element, so I update my object in the list. But while sending object parameter arrives outdated, for example:

If you would LIKE to one that has 0 likes, stay at 1 like, when you click and view detail I get 0 likes yet.

Comment: Sorry, it may be unclear, the point is that update values of an object within a list and it works, but when trying to send that value to another view, not working.

Comment: could you please create a CodePen?